# problem with setjmp and longjmp to switch between 2 functions

Tags: c, setjmp

I am trying to implement a code which continuously switched between functions fun() and main() which do nothing but to print on screen infinitely. I am trying to switch by setjmp and longjmp and using SIGALRM signal in C.
But when I run it, it just works once and then doesn't switch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf b1, b2;
int cur = 0;

void handlesig(int sig) {
    if(!cur) {
        cur = 1;
        setjmp(b2);
        longjmp(b1, 1);
    }
    else {
        cur = 0;
        setjmp(b1);
        longjmp(b2, 1);
    }
}

void fun() {    
    while(1) {
        printf("I am in function fun()\n");
        for(int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++);
    }
}

int main() {    
    signal(SIGALRM, handlesig);
    ualarm(900000, 900000);                     //send SIGALRM after each 900000 microseconds
    if(!setjmp(b1))
        fun();                                  //will be run when setjmp returns 0
    while(1) {                      
        printf("I am in function main()\n");    //will be run when setjmp returns 1
        for(int x = 0; x < 100000000; x++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting what is the problem with this code.

Comment: Did you try running it in the debugger?

Comment: @JoelFan: That's just going to produce a mess of corrupt frames.

Comment: in that case add a whole lot more printf statements.

Comment: Are you sure that the crude "delay" loops aren't optimised out?

Comment: I used printf to see if the the handler function gets called regularly, found out that it only gets called once.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior because the lifetime of the block where `setjmp` was called on `b1` or `b2` in the signal handler ends as soon as `longjmp` is called (in the very next line). The next time you call `longjmp` trying to return to a `jmp_buf` that is no longer valid, the behavior is undefined, and this manifests as the state being utterly corrupted.

You can write **a hack** to work around this by using `sigaltstack` and `SA_ONSTACK` flag for the signal handler to have multiple stacks, so that even though the `jmp_buf` is formally invalid, it's in practice not clobbered. But this is not a valid program, just one which happens to work in practice *on some systems* (not all). Ultimately, there is no (valid/reliable) way to do what you're asking for with `setjmp` and `longjmp`; context switching requires a *strictly stronger* primitive than what they provide.

Comment: I believe `setcontext/getcontext` is explicitly designed to do what OP [ultimately] wants.

Comment: @Craig: But they were removed from Posix 2008: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap03.html#tag_22_03_01_07